# Autoresize infowindow from xib file depended from the content in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xib, autoresize

I try to resize my custom infowindow which is created in a xib file from a UIView.The width depends from content of the window, but i have not find any solution.I tried everything in the storyboard but nothing happens.I have upload a screenshot to see my problem:

Here is my code from the UIView of the xib

```
public protocol nonPaidDelegate:  class {
func didTapMapsSelectButton()
}

class MapInfoWindow: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var titleInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var adressInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonAction: UIButton!

open var delegate:nonPaidDelegate?
@IBAction func didTapInButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.delegate?.didTapMapsSelectButton()

    print("button tapped")
}


class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "MapInfoWindowView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
}
```

In my viewcontroller i call the MapInfoWindow

```
var infoWindow = MapInfoWindow()
 infoWindow = loadNiB()
```

and i create the infoWindow UIView for the marker:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    if let venueItem = marker.userData as? Venue {
        infoWindow.titleInfo?.text = venueItem.name
        infoWindow.adressInfo?.text = venueItem.locationName
        NSLog(venueItem.name!)
    } else {
        NSLog("Did tap a normal marker")
    }

    return UIView()
}
```

}

[image: screenshot from the view]

Comment: Unclear what the problem even is. What is supposed to happen and what is happening instead? Where is your code that is supposed to make it happen? We have no idea from this what you are doing, what you want to do, and what is resulting.

Comment: how many label you are using?

Comment: you are right guys i updated my question with some code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal programmatically like this,I have used two label(`titleLabel` & `snippetLabel`):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
            let infoWindowView = UIView()
            let titleStringWidth = marker.title?.widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0))
            var infoWidth = 0
                if titleStringWidth!+10>self.view.frame.size.width - 50 {
                  infoWindowView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 50
                  infoWidth = Int(self.view.frame.size.width - 50.0)
                }else {
                    infoWindowView.frame.size.width = titleStringWidth!+10
                    infoWidth = Int(titleStringWidth!)+10
                }

            infoWindowView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 50
            infoWindowView.backgroundColor  = UIColor.white
            let titleLabel = UILabel()
            titleLabel.frame.size.width  = infoWindowView.frame.size.width-10
            titleLabel.numberOfLines     = 0
            titleLabel.lineBreakMode     = .byWordWrapping
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
            titleLabel.frame.origin.x    = 3
            titleLabel.frame.origin.y    = 5

            titleLabel.text = "your text"
            titleLabel.textAlignment     = .center
            titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            let actualNumberOfLinesForTiltle = titleLabel.numberOfVisibleLines
            titleLabel.frame.size.height = CGFloat(actualNumberOfLinesForTiltle*20)

            let snippetLabel = UILabel()
            snippetLabel.frame.size.width = infoWindowView.frame.size.width-10
            snippetLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            snippetLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            snippetLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
            snippetLabel.text = "your text"
            snippetLabel.textAlignment = .center
            snippetLabel.sizeToFit()
            let snippet_y = 20*actualNumberOfLinesForTiltle+10
            let actualNumberOfLinesForSnippet = snippetLabel.numberOfVisibleLines
            snippetLabel.frame.origin.x = 3
            snippetLabel.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(snippet_y)
            snippetLabel.frame.size.height = CGFloat(actualNumberOfLinesForSnippet*20)

            let visibleHeightOfView = 15+actualNumberOfLinesForTiltle*20+actualNumberOfLinesForSnippet*20
            infoWindowView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: infoWidth, height: visibleHeightOfView)

            infoWindowView.addSubview(titleLabel)
            infoWindowView.addSubview(snippetLabel)
        return infoWindowView    
}
```

and add this extension

```
extension UILabel {
    var numberOfVisibleLines: Int {
        let textSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let rHeight: Int = lroundf(Float(self.sizeThatFits(textSize).height))
        let charSize: Int = lroundf(Float(self.font.pointSize))
        return rHeight / charSize
    }

}
extension String {

    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        let size = self.size(attributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
```

Comment: I think all this code can be done from the storyboard of xib file..I integrated the code and as i saw the infoWindow starts with the 100% of the screen and it can be changed depended on the int you put here:infoWindow.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 50

Comment: `self.view.frame.size.width - 50` is maximum width if your text size is less than this, it will be small